# Photo picker error - Connection to plugin interrupted while in use

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm getting following error on iPad device when I try to scale an image during image upload from gallery.

This error doesn't happen on simulator. This also doesn't occur when I use camera to take photo and scale on iPad device.

App doesn't crash, it's an error only.

Doing a search doesn't give any solution.

How to fix this issue?

```
MyApp[766:521800] [lifecycle  ] [u 65F7F957-8A07-4532-B921-0EA850CEB8E6:m (null)] [com.apple.mobileslideshow.photo-picker(1.0)] Connection to plugin interrupted while in use.
MyApp[766:521800] [lifecycle  ] [u 65F7F957-8A07-4532-B921-0EA850CEB8E6:m (null)] [com.apple.mobileslideshow.photo-picker(1.0)] Connection to plugin invalidated while in use.
MyApp[766:521041] viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
MyApp[766:521041] [Generic] -[PUPhotoPickerHostViewController viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:] Error Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
```

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve or workaround this?  Using an iPad device with a large Photos library, I am get the exact same errors using either PHPickerViewController or UIImagePickerController.  Both pickers seem to work on iPadOS 14.2 simulator.

Comment: No, I gave up as I couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Are you using SwiftUI? How do you invoke the PHPickerViewController?

Comment: No, I'm not using SwiftUI

Comment: I has same issue. And found some photo from android will cause this issue. But I had no idea.